# Saving parent object with has_one association to polymorphic child in one go gives error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to save a parent object (Report) and the associated polymorphic child (Attachment) in one go - the association is a 'has_one'.

I'm using the '.create' method on the Report with a params hash containing the nested contents for the child, but I'm getting the error 'Validation failed: Attachment attachable can't be blank'.

What I have is (simplyfied):

Parent model:

```
Class Report
  has_one :attachment, as: :attachable, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :refdate, :link_name, :type_name, :attachment_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachment
```

Child model:

```
Class Attachment
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  attr_accessible :file

  validates_presence_of :attachable
  validates_presence_of :file
```

Controller:

```
ReportsController
  def create
    @report = Report.create!(params[:report])
  end
```

View (haml):

```
= form_for @report, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = f.select :type_name
  = f.text_field :link_name
  = f.text_field :refdate
  = f.fields_for :attachment_attributes, html: { multipart: true } do |p|
    = p.file_field :file
  = f.submit
```

Adapting the controller I can achieve that first the parent is saved to the db and afterwards the attachment is saved (here `attachable` is filled automatically by Rails), but I'd like to avoid this two-step save process, to make sure that either both are saved, or none of the two.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!